# Redirecionamento de domínios em loja virtual

Tags: redirecionamento

Bom dia!

Estou finalizando o desenvolvimento de uma loja virtual que vou trabalhar com aluguel. Até aí tudo bem: estou com o seguinte problema.

Quero deixar todos os clientes utilizaram sempre o mesmo sistema administrativo e loja, mas, claro que com seus respectivos banco de dados.

Exemplo:  `www.shoplivre.com.br/cliente01`

Mais queria que no navegar ficasse a url do cliente. Como posso fazer isso? É possível?

Exemplo: `www.lojamil.com.br`

Comment: É possível sim. Qual tecnologia esta utilizando? Sua página de login é unificada?

Comment: Você é dono dos dois domínios?

Comment: Boa tarde, Vinícius sim será unificada, a loja virtual também tipo quero utilizar sempre a mesma plataforma e no admin o cliente pode deixar a loja do seu jeito. tipo http://www.iset.com.br/?site=ishopping&page=201, essa loja eu já fui clientes dele e é o mesmo admin pra todas as lojas e também a mesma loja pra todos ela vem com layout padrão e no admin consigo mudar.

Comment: Guilherme vai funcionar assim, vou alugar a loja, então quando um cliente alugar a loja eu vou cadastrar em uma tabela no banco de dados, então cada clientes terá uma id dai vou conseguir identificar cada cliente.

Comment: Preciso saber se você é dono ou adm dos domínios (não estou falando da hospedagem), tendo controle sobre os domínios posso dizer que é possível, claro que se você tiver acesso a uma linguagem dinâmica como php em ambos domínios é possível controlar os cookies para compartilhar a sessão.

Comment: vou ter acesso a todos os domínios vão estar todos no meu vcs,

Comment: Sim é possível! Fiz o mesmo no meu site alterando os domínios conforme o tutorial: https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-alterar-os-nameservers-de-dominio-de-ponto-para-o-novo-provedor-de-hospedagem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Só que pra resposta ficar boa, é preciso saber com que tecnologia de servidor HTTP estamos lidando.

A técnica é simples e é baseada nos seus registros DNS: tendo o domínio registrado, basta fazê-lo apontar para o subdomínio correto através do registro CNAME. [Aqui tem uma boa introdução sobre CNAME](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/58317?hl=pt-BR). [Aqui você tem mais detalhes sobre como ele funciona para o Registro.br](https://registro.br/tecnologia/caracteristicas-tecnicas.html).

Além disso, você pode ainda fazer com que outra máquina controle o domínio pra você, definindo entradas MASTER e SLAVE no seu registro de DNS. Ao definir MASTER e SLAVE ao invés de entradas manuais, você está dizendo à autoridade de registro DNS (o Registro.br é uma autoridade de registro) que uma outra máquina fará a atualização dinâmica dos registros DNS sem você precisar entrar toda vez no painel e modificar. [O Hostgator oferece este tipo de serviço e ensina o passo-a-passo aqui](http://faq.hostgator.com.br/content/55/370/pt-br/alterando-os-dns-de-seu-dom%C3%ADnio-no-registrobr.html).

Por fim, a configuração sobre qual subdomínio seu servidor HTTP irá devolver depende da tecnologia.